# Getting "Cannot read property 'http' of undefined" with Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working on an Angular 7 project, and I'm facing a weird problem that took me some considerable time to identify, but I don't know why this is happening and I hope you guys can help me. I created a service using angular-cli, and then I implemented it as follows:

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
    import {forkJoin, Observable} from "rxjs";
    import {map} from "rxjs/operators";

    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class SampleService {

      constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
      }

      save(sample: Sample): Observable {
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/samples", sample).pipe(map(this.parser));
      }

      saveAll(samples: Sample[]): Observable {
        return forkJoin(samples.map(this.save))
      }

      private parser = (value): Sample => new Sample(value.name);
    }

    export class Sample {
      name: string;

      constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
      }
    }
```

I put a breakpoint on each method. When I run it I get the following:

[image: First breakpoint stop]

As you can see, everything seems ok in the first breakpoint, so let's go to the next.

[image: Second breakpoint stop]

Now everything is undefined, and I get the following error in the console:

```
    ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'http' of undefined
```

If I change this line:

```
    forkJoin(samples.map(this.save))
```

to

```
    forkJoin(samples.map(sample => this.save(sample)))
```

When I rerun the code. I get:

[image: Third breakpoint stop]

And now everything seems to be ok, and the code works just fine. As a java developer, in a similar situation, the first way is comparable to a method reference and it would work just fine, why in TypeScript it doesn't?

Comment: this is how javascript works. If you want to keep the first option then write it as instance function https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/%27this%27-in-TypeScript#use-instance-functions

Comment: Its related to the context of object. In first case context will change however in second option context will always be the same.  Refer- http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: `return forkJoin(samples.map(sample => this.save(sample)));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is contextual. Every function defined using `function` definition gets its own `this`.
Arrow function definition works differently in that, it binds the parent context to the function body, making `this` refer to the parent `this`. It is similar to defining a function and binding it explicitly like:

```
function(doc){
//function body
}).bind(this)
```